# Interchange limit and sum if limit exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\Big(f(m)+g(m,n)\Big)=c$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}g(m,n)=0$$

in which $c$ is finite.

I was wondering if it could then be said that

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f(m)=c.$$ I have looked up related concepts such as uniform convergence but I am curious if the fact that we know the limit exists allows us to interchange the sum and limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(m,n)=1$ if $m=n$ and $0$ if $m \neq n$. Let $f(m)=0$ for all $n$. Then $g(m,n) \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ for each $m$ and $\sum [f(m)+g(m,n)]=1$ for all $n$. But it is not true that $\sum f(m)=1$.

Note that DCT gives an affirmative answer under an extra hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Not a priori. You can do it if there is a function $k$ s.t. $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty |h(m)|\quad \text{and}\quad \forall m\geq 1, |f(m)+g(m)h(n)|\leq k(m).$$ The claim follow by Dominated convergence theorem.